# Apply some function to a variable from its string name

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I've got a list of  strings `list = c("string_1", "string_2", ...)` and, based on this vector, I know there are dataframes named `df_string_1, df_string_2, ...` in my environment.

My code is like:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)){
  res = function(i) // dataframe depending on i, same ncol as df_string_i
  rbind(df_list[i],res) // that's the line I don't know how to code
}
```

I can't find a way to get the dataframe df_string_i at each iteration.
My attempt was to get its name with `paste("df_",list[i],sep="")` but then, what can I do with this string as I need the variable to be in the rbind?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a situation with data.frames named df_string_1, ..., df_string_n, you would be better off, in the long run, storing these in a list and using tools such as `lapply`. To solve the current issue, use `get`:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)){
  res = function(i) // dataframe depending on i, same ncol as df_string_i
  rbind(get(paste0("df_",list[i])),res)
}
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to the answer by a few seconds. I'm deleting mine. However, note that the data frames are stored as `df_list_i`, so it would have to be `paste0('df_list_',i)`.

Comment: get() works perfect! Thank you. Yes I'm aware of all the apply functions, but it's difficult to use it given the structure of the data I have. Thank you shreyasgm as well :)

Comment: Thanks @shreyasgm. I think the OP edited this. The latest update has `list = c("string_1", "string_2", ...)` and `paste("df_",list[i],sep="")`.